# favicon.ico:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, favicon

I'm going through a javascript tutorial right now and noticed that all of my HTML files are receiving this favicon.ico:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found) error. I know that this has been answered before several times, but I can't get any of those selected solutions to work on my machine. If anyone can help me out, I would greatly appreciate it.

The line that I've come across a lot is

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
```

And it's not working for me and any other variation of it. Do I have to make any other directories or do something I'm not thinking of?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Do you have the favicon.ico file in your public folder?

Comment: It's not an error that indicates anything is wrong, the browser is just probing for whether that file exists. If it doesn't, it doesn't matter either. But you can actually create and serve a favicon.ico if you don't want to see the 404 anymore ^^

Comment: Most browsers are looking for a file called `favicon.ico` at the server root by default in order to display it as the tab's icon. If your website doesn't have one, just ignore the warning. To use your own icon, replace the `#` with your actual filename. You can use an ico file, or a png.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this error in 2 ways

1. You need to have your favicon in your project folder and you need to load the favicon.
2. If you don't want to use favicon then you can use below line to remove that error link

   < link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,=">